# Periodic build in Hudson

Tags: build, hudson

I have so far used `Periodic build` in `Hudson` where the schedule `* * * * *` builds the project every minute and `5 * * * *` builds the project every x:05, x+1:05 etc.

But what is the way to build the project every 5 mins??? (Or any given time period)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
*/5 * * * *
```

Will do the build **every 5 minutes**.